# Find a polynomial $f(x)$ s.t. $f(x) ≡ 0 \pmod{p^e}$ has only one solution but $f(x)≡ 0 \pmod{p^{(e+1)}}$ has $p$ solutions

Tags: number-theory

Find a polynomial $f(x)$  s.t. $f(x) ≡ 0 \pmod{p^e}$ has only one solution in $Z(p^e)$ but $f(x)≡ 0 \pmod{p^{(e+1)}}$ has $p$ solutions in $Z(p^e+1))$ for any $e≥1$ and odd primes.

I didn't find such a polynomial.

Suppose $f(x)≡0 \pmod{p^e}$ has a solution. Denote $x(e). e$ is a subscript.

Suppose the solution of  $f(x)\equiv 0 \pmod{p^{e+1}}$ is $x(e+1)$. Then the $x(e+1)$ should be of the form $x(e+1)=x(e)+(p^e)\times k(e)$.

To find $k(e)$, we need to solve $f'(x(e))\cdot k(e)≡-q(e) \pmod p$.
$f(x(e))=(p^e)\times q(e)$

If $f(x) ≡ 0 \pmod{p^{(e+1)})}$ has $p$ solutions in $Z(p^e+1))$, then we have
$f'(x(e))≡q(e)≡ 0 \pmod p$. So $q(e)$ should be $0$. This implies $f(x(e))=0$.
So $f(x)=[x-x(e)]\times g(x)$.

Since $f'(x)=g(x)+[x-x(e)]\times g'(x)$ and $f'(x(e))≡ 0\pmod p$, we have

$g(x(e))≡ 0 \pmod p$.

I didn't find a polynomial $f(x)$ satisfying this equation.

Comment: @Murtuza Vadharia : You approved an edit supposedly setting this in "latex" (actually MathJax) that did not properly use \pmod, so that you saw things like $f(x)\equiv 0 (mod p)$ rather than $f(x)\equiv 0 \pmod p$ (coded as f(x)\equiv 0 \pmod p), etc.  Instead of clicking on "Approve", you can click on "Improve" and fix things like that. $\qquad$

Comment: Let $ e=1 $, let $ p $ be an arbitrary prime and consider $ f(x) = (x-1)^2 $. Then, $ f $ has only one root in $ \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} $, but has $ p $ roots in $ \mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z} $.

Comment: Can we find a polynomial satisfying this for any e≥1? I can find some polynomials for some specific e's.